# Social page news feed not working on firefox

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, firefox, facebook-page

I am trying to display the facebook and twitter news feed on a website. I am able to display it in chrome as well as safari but not able to display in the firefox.

**This is not my page I found from google.**

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FGoogle&width=600&colorscheme=light&show_faces=true&border_color&stream=true&header=true&height=435" scrolling="yes" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:600px; height:430px; background: white; float:left; " allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Even I checked http://jsfiddle.net/tLkpvhnb/ link which is working on chrome but not working on firefox.

firefox version:Version 62.0b4 (32-bit)

Can you help me out in this?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the code per se, but is due to Firefox’ Tracking Protection options. Check what that is set to in your config, it is likely set to “always”. In that case, you should see a little “shield” icon in the address bar before the site address. Click on it to get more info.

Comment: @CBroe, It's not working on private browsing in the firefox and working on the normal browser. Just know I checked

Comment: I set "Always" now it's not working on the normal browser also.

Comment: @CBroe If "Tracking Protection options" is enable then social feed will not display else display the feed.